# How to user Laravel resource with /user api of Authentication

Tags: laravel, api, resources, laravel-passport

I am building a project with Laravel and Vue using Axios and Passport.

My authentication is working and generating token and saving in my local storage to check for login.

I am also getting the data using

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
return $request->user();
});
```

However, my user also has some relationship which I have described in my model like

```
public function types()
{

    return $this->belongsTo(types::class, 'type_id');

}
```

and my user resource looks like this

```
 public function toArray($request)
{

    $array = parent::toArray($request);
    $array['group'] = $this->groups;
    $array['type']  =   $this->types->typeName;
    return $array;
}
```

So when user login I am trying to get user data using auth:api however I want a relationship to come with it.

I tried

````php
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return UserResource::collection($request->user());
});

and get error
> Call to undefined method App\User::mapInto()

I also tried 
```php
return new UserResource::collection($request->user());
````

> error: syntax error, unexpected 'collection' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$'

```
return UserResource::collection($request->user()-get());
```

> error: Trying to get property 'typeName' of non-object

So what am I doing wrong? thanks for your time and if need more details please let me know

Comment: the `types` relationship can return `null`, you will need to check to make sure the relationship actually exists ... and you should probably work on the naming of relationships to make it more obvious when something returns 1 or many (singular or plural), will make things easier

Comment: hi @lagbox, relationship does exists and it's not returning null as all the data has types column filled with factories.

Comment: Hi @DinoNumić, thanks for your reply. If you check my question I have tried that but it is returning error too

Comment: @Zee I have removed my comment as I was not completely sure and I had to check it first. I have checked your question but you are still calling collection on UserResource. You can't do it if you a single model instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve similar, if not better results using `Eager loading`. [source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Sample:

```php
Route::get('me', function(Request $request) {
    $request->user()->load('types');
});
```